# Fastlane : Supply - Is it possible to create a new apk and upload the same to playstore via fastlane?

Tags: android, google-play, fastlane, google-play-developer-api

Is it possible to create a new Android app apk and upload the same to playstore via fastlane?

Is it possible to create a new app in plasytore via fastlane? Or do we require to manually create an app in playstore and upload the apk first time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps have to manually created in the Play Console because there are legal terms and conditions that must be accepted by a human for each app. You also have to answer questions to give your app an age rating. Fastlane can't and shouldn't do either of these.

Comment: Does that also mean that, we cannot publish first APK using fastlane. But we can always publish updates of an existing app using fastlane?

Comment: I cannot comment on fastlane. But the Google Play Publisher API supports publishing updates. https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/#publishing so fastlane has the ability to add support.

Comment: This answers my question. Thanks Nick